How to add Gradle subproject to Gradle plugin
How can I add a submodule to my Gralde Plugin?
dependencies {
  api(gradleApi())
  api(gradleKotlinDsl())
  api(project(":lib"))
  implementation(gradleKotlinDsl())
  implementation(libs.bundles.implementation)
  testImplementation(libs.bundles.testImplementation)
  testImplementation(gradleTestKit())
}

When publishing it the downstream projects says:
Could not find kotlin-dsl-gradle-plugin:lib:unspecified.

